# Why when using the "env -i" command the environment is not really empty?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

I am playing with the command `env` and the option `-i` of the command. According to the documentation when I use `env -i ./myscript.sh` I should be getting an empty environment for my script.

I gave it a try with the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script: command_env.sh
echo "User name : $USER"
echo "Home : $HOME"
echo "Path : $PATH" 

echo "These are the environment variables"
echo "#####################"
env
echo "#####################"
```

In this script, as you can see I just print a few variables (like `USER`, `HOME` and `PATH`) and later I am using the command `env` to print all the environment variables.

I was expecting that there would be no variables in the environment. But I am getting the following result when I execute my script with `env -i`.

```
$ env -i ./command_env.sh
User name : 
Home : 
Path : /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
These are the environment variables
#####################
PWD=/home/username/Test/bash/env
SHLVL=1
_=/usr/bin/env
#####################
$
```

What I see is that the environment is not fully empty as it contains the following environment variables:

- `PATH`
- `PWD`
- `SHLVL`
- `_`

Does anyone know why is it working like that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hint: try `env -i env`, i.e. `env` directly invoking `env`. Is the output empty? What program sits between two `env`s in your case?

Comment: Similarly `PWD` and `SHLVL` are set by the shell itself.